# gl_fragColor with multiple textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, fragment-shader

I currently have two textures being applied to a single object.  Eventually there will be a couple more added to that, but I am having trouble getting the current two to work properly.

At the moment, I am setting my fragcolor to the two images added together.  Literally all I am doing is something similar to :

```
gl_FragColor = texture1 + texture2;
```

I am sure there is a better way to do such things to begin with, but it also creates the problem that where the images overlap is added together (obviously), which is not what I am trying to do with my current project.

I am not sure if this is simply an issue with only my fragColor, where there's some built in function of GLSL to do something like this, or if I need to do something like combine the images before hand in some other fashion.

**EDIT ::**  Example of the color adding I meant : https://i.stack.imgur.com/auHMK.png

Comment: As long as we don't know what you are "trying to do with your current project", we cannot give you any explanations. Surely adding two colors together works, but if you want to combine them in a different way, then just do so. Otherwise tell us what effect you want to achieve.

Comment: I apologize for that, I didn't realize how poorly worded that was.  All I want to do is have the images layered in their specific order, not blending together at all.  I've messed with it quite a bit, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to not blend them together in one form or another.  I'm sure it is something simplistic that will make me feel a tad dense.

Comment: If you want them layered and not blended in any way, then this will always result in the second texture color.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that.  I believe I have a handle on the order the images are placed, but what it is doing now would happen regardless of the order.  It is adding the overlapping pixels together rather than just applying the most recent one over the previous.  I'm still not sure if I just have to change the way I am passing in the fragColor or if I have to do something to group the textures together before hand, or something else I'm not even thinking of.

Comment: The thing is, you always have two colors, as you read both textures. So the second texture is always the most recent one. Or do you want the previous one only to show up where the recent one is transparent, then you definitely need some kind of blending.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting what adding two colors will actually mean - say if the first texture 50 % red and the second is 50 % red, the end result will be 100 % red. That will also mean that if texture1 is all white, texture2 will not have anything to say at all (since the color values will be > 1.0f). What you want is blending - which you can do in the shader (see answer), or you can do through glBlend - operations.

Comment: I understand what adding two colors does, the problem is that I don't want to add them together at all, but instead just ignore (or perhaps discard if that works better) any part of the textures that are "underneath" the others, I just didn't know how to go about doing this.  I believe your example is on the right track for this, I'll go experiment with it now.

Comment: @Shamrock But as said, you need a notion for a texture to be under another texture, or said other way, you have to define where the upper texture is or where there is no upper texture, because when you read the color from the texture, you always have a color. You have to define when this color is transparent and the lower texture is seen through and this is usually done with the alpha channel and some kind of blending. And that's exactly what Arne's answer is doing.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that was what needed to be done after looking at his answer.  I've been trying to get it working, though it is still pretty confusing to me.  I can make one image to kind of subtract itself from the other, which I think is what I want(?), but then I can't get that 'subtracted' image to show up properly.  I am sure it will click for me if I continue working on it and really think about what Arne's little code snippet is doing in relation to my setup.

Comment: Could you give an example of two textures you want to draw, and what your intended end result is?

Comment: Well, for right now I am only using two very simple primitive shapes as place holders while I try to learn more about OpenGL, but I will post an image link in the main question for you.  Basically, in this situation, I want the orange box to look like it is in front of the green circle, and completely solid so there's none of that color adding going on.  I have gotten a bunch of different results as I played around with it, but I've never been able to get both textures applied without that overlapping area either added or subtracted together.

Comment: Ok, your textures should use an alpha channel to mark the area that is to be drawn/not drawn. If they do it should work either with the answer I posted, or with standard blending using two drawcalls instead of one. You can see how you enable blending at http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm

Comment: Well, I am able to modify the textures to remove part of the green circle and it would work, but that isn't the ideal way to do it for when the actual graphics will be in place.  Sparing a long explanation, basically the area represented by the orange box will change into various textures based on the users preference, and I'd like to be able to just apply the texture and have it work rather than having to make all kinds of graphic combinations with the 'green circle' area.  I also have blending enabled already for the transparency of the png images, is there simply one more I need to add?

Comment: @Shamrock let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2967/discussion-between-arne-bergene-fossaa-and-shamrock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you want to blend the two textures in the shader instead of doing it with regular blending. Something like this should work, I believe - you can probably simplify this if you make assumptions.

```
gl_FragColor = backgroundcolor;
gl_FragColor = (gl_FragColor*(1-texture1.a))+(texture1*texture1.a);
gl_FragColor = (gl_FragColor*(1-texture2.a))+(texture2*texture2.a);
```

EDIT:

The final answer here ended up being regular blending, and not blending in the fragment shader.

Comment: This answer was not the final one for my particular problem, but it was solved thanks to Arne's patience on helping me out.  For others that may have a similar problem, be sure to read the chat between me and Arne linked in the comments to the first post, as the better solution to my problem is found in there.  Thanks again for all your time, Arne.